# How to enable adding both feature classes / tables and layers from TOC to a script tool parameter input?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.2

I have developed a script tool which will allow a user to specify input feature class or table and then will process it.

Surprised I haven't noticed this before: I cannot find which data type my input features parameter should be to let users specify both feature class / tables (by drag-n-drop from Catalog window or browsing to a place on the disk) and layers from the table of contents (TOC) in case they have already added a feature class / table to the map document.

`Dataset` and `Feature Class` type will let me to browse to tables/feature classes and feature classes only, respectively. `Layer` will let me specify the added feature layer from the TOC only.

[image]

Core GP tools such as Frequency and many others, in contrast, will let you drag-n-drop feature classes/tables and choose a layer/table in case you have some added to the TOC.

I've read through the [list of GP data types from the Esri Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/01m1/pdf/Geoprocessing_data_types.pdf), but cannot find any that will help me. Am I hitting one of the limitations of the custom script tools? I am on 10.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Table View`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/supplement/data-types-for-geoprocessing-tool-parameters.htm) parameter (latest GP data types [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/supplement/pdf/Geoprocessing_data_types.pdf)) will allow you to select both tables and feature classes on disk as well as in the TOC. This will work in Model Builder as well as toolbox scripts.

As a drop down from TOC:

[image]

When opening from disk:
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

Feature Layer should be the data type that allows you to do both.

Comment: Feature layer can indeed let you use both feature classes and layers in the TOC, but they don't let you in tables or tables in the TOC. I have updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you sure? I can select a table if I have feature layer as the data type.

Comment: Layer is not the same as Feature Layer.

Comment: @ian, yea, I am pretty sure. I get 'Invalid drop item' message when trying to drop a table into a parameter area. If you browse, only feature classes and .lyr files are listed.